# Unable to use the "emacs" command in Windows 7 command prompt

Tags: emacs, windows-7, cmd, command-prompt

I have downloaded and installed emacs from http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html.

However when I tried to use the command for emacs on my command prompt

```
C:\Users\BTDemapan\Desktop\Thesis emacs totality.py
```

I get this message

```
'emacs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I could only manually open the file using the GNUEmacs Client by clicking on it from its folder location.

Comment: This is off topic, but you may want to use the latest version of emacs from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/emacs-24.3-bin-i386.zip). The version at the above link seems to be out of date.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the directory where Emacs executable is to PATH
environment variable.

Have a look at [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-xp).

You can set PATH temporarily from the command line, or permanently with
"My Computer" > "Properties" > "Advanced" > "Environment Variables" > "Path"
and rebooting.

Comment: No need to reboot a station for just changing the PATH variable. Maybe just reload the applications that could need it and are already started, like currently running command prompts.